# Rewrite cycle in functional style

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I've created simple function: it has array as input and id. Function suppose to take all elements 'before' given idea.

```
    function takeBefore(stars, id) {
        var taken = [];
        for(var i = 0, length = stars.length; i < length; i++) {
            if (stars[i].itemId === id) {
                break;
            }

            taken.push(stars[i]);
        }

        return taken;
    }
```

Code below does the job, but recently I became a bit picky. Would like get rid of for-loop and some functional style.

Is that possible to use `underscore` or `ES5` functions to do same job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of stuff is usually called `takeWhile`/`dropWhile`. You can implement them using the boolean iterator `every()`:

```
function takeWhile(array, predicate) {
    var pos = -1;
    var all = array.every(function(x, n) { 
        return (pos = n), predicate(x);
    })
    return array.slice(0, pos + all);
}

function dropWhile(array, predicate) {
    var pos = -1;
    var all = array.every(function(x, n) { 
        return (pos = n), predicate(x);
    })
    return array.slice(pos + all);
}


a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
b = takeWhile(a, function(x) { return x < 5 }) // 1,2,3,4
b = dropWhile(a, function(x) { return x < 5 }) // 5,6,7
```

Comment: that works really well! could you plz expain `every`.. I thought it returns boolean value, how come it used as pos + all ?

Comment: @alexanderb: this is a hack actually. When used with `+`, booleans are converted to ints (true=1, false=0) and I'm using that to shift the position by one in case all elements match the predicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5];
x.slice(0, x.indexOf(3));
```

Results:

```
[1, 2]
```